# How do I turn int into float in C?

Tags: c

I have a simple question in C. How do i turn an int value into a float, so I can add nonintegers to it.

Like say

```
int i = 1;
```

How can I add 0.5 to i to get a float number 1.5?
I've tried:

```
float j = (float)i + 0.5;
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Pleas help.

Comment: That is precisely how you'd do it. So define "not work".

Comment: My guess is when you `printf` it, you're using the wrong format string.

Comment: *"Doesn't seem to work. Pleas help."* is not a valid problem statement.

Comment: float j = i + 0.5;
    
    printf("%f", j);

Comment: try to print j like `printf("%f",j);` may be it can help you.

Answer (score 7):

I guess, you have used wrong **format specifier**. In gcc compiler following program working fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     int i = 1;
     float j = (float)i + 0.5;
     printf("%f\n",j);
}
```

**Output:**

```
1.500000
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote your code in visual studio 2012 and it perfectly works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    float j = (float)i + 0.05;
    printf("%f\n", j);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

You can simply convert by putting float before the int type variable as shown in below example.

((float)number/total)*100

Comment: How is this different from what OP does?